# how to remove x amount of data between 2 words

Tags: regex, notepad++

how to remove some random words between 2 selected words in notepad++ using regex...
here is an example to my question

```
DATA100003165663180:sdhfdsdf

DATA:cuoleL

DATA0004513337081:fsdfsd

DATAjhh07016550687:csd

DATA2369343834:1dsdsdbhz
```

here you can see i need to remove all the words that are between `DATA` and `":"` in such a way that i get `DATA:xxx` and not `DATA006554something:xxx`
and as you can see on line 2 there is no extra things that needs to be removed after DATA so the regex should ignore such lines

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(DATA)[^:]*:(.+)
```

and replace the found matches with `$1:$2`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/IcIzqr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this for search `DATA([^:])*` and this for replace `DATA`  making sure you checked the regular expression option at the left bottom corner. Click Replace All

Comment: thanks for the regex.. it helped me.. any other way to do this aswell??? just wondering